# Where can I find .deb packages for specific programs?

Tags: installation, deb

For major programs on Ubuntu, I can download them using

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>
```

but sometimes, I need higher versions than the apt source, and PPA's download speed is too slow for me.

So I have to download .deb packages directly.

For example, I want to install the latest version of syslinux, where to download the .deb package?

Now I know the answer is http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/syslinux/ , but how can I get this address if I don't know? Similarly, how to find latest .deb packages for gftp, wine etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when some programs are available for Ubuntu or Debian You can find their .debs on the website (just google it and search download section). For example [wine](http://www.winehq.org/download).

Sometimes You can just download binary version like in [scilab](http://www.scilab.org/products/scilab/download) or [firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/pl/download/?product=firefox-9.0.1&os=linux&lang=pl) case. In the latter case You need some work to make them work as those integrated into Ubuntu. But in general to run them You need to find a bin folder and click twice some file. For example:

```
ScilabVERSION/bin/scilab
```

Or great 3D modelling soft: Blender:

Just download it, untar the folder - right click - extract here, and find the executable icon called blender. Click it twice.

There also are ppa's - to add sources of software to Your repository.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your solution, and I happened to find the website http://packages.ubuntu.com/ is satisfied.